# Inferring properties from extended interface

Tags: typescript

#### Background

I have the following base interface:

```
interface IVehicle {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly price: number;
}
```

And then these two:

```
interface ICar {
  readonly type: 'land';
  readonly manufacturers: ICarManufacturer[];
}
```

```
interface IAirplane {
  readonly type: 'air';
  readonly manufacturers: IAirplaneManufacturer[];
}
```

A Vehicle can only be a Car or an Airplane. These are fairly simplified for the sake of this post...

---

#### What I tried

To solve this, I started by extending each "sub class", like:

```
interface Airplane extends Vehicle {
```

which works fine, but I also want to be able to do the following in parts of my code where the type is not immediately known:

```
const vehicle = getVehicle(id); // Returns a "Vehicle"
if (vehicle.type === 'car') {
  processCarManufacturers(manufacturers); // Fn expects a "Car" - How to infer that type from the "if" above?
```

I also tried with Generics, but this seems wrong:

```
interface Vehicle<T extends Car | Vehicle> {...}
interface Car extends Vehicle<Car> {...}
```

but even then, the inference didn't seem to work like this...

---

I want to be able to use `IVehicle`, and via some property be able to infer the rest of the object properties - all while also, in other parts of the code, being able to use `ICar` with all its 4 properties.

It seems almost like a circular dependency of some sort. Not sure if I'm going down a rabbit hole...

Comment: Do you have implementations to go with the interfaces, or do you just have the types to work with?

Comment: @VLAZ, can you elaborate? Not following...

Comment: Are there actual classes that implement those interfaces? Or do you just do something like `const plane: IAirplane = { type: "air", manufacturers: []}` - using the types with plain objects?

Comment: @VLAZ, ah, just the latter.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The answer can depend on it and the simpler one I was thinking of works best with just types. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `Vehicle` class a simple union of all the possible vehicles. This can work like this:

```js
interface IVehicle {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly price: number;
}

interface ICar extends IVehicle{
  readonly type: 'land';
  readonly manufacturers: ICarManufacturer[];
}

interface IAirplane extends IVehicle {
  readonly type: 'air';
  readonly manufacturers: IAirplaneManufacturer[];
}

type Vehicle = 
  | ICar
  | IAirplane
```

`IVehicle` is the basis and both `ICar` and `IAirplane` extend it. That makes sure they each have the same shared properties `id` and `price`.

The `Vehicle` type is then a union of `ICar` and `IAirplane`. What is important here is that they both share the `type` property. This allows you to use it as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). When you do

```js
if (vehicle.type === 'land') {
  // ...
}
```

Then inside the `if` the vehicle can only be a car because it's the only member of the union with `type` being set to a literal `"land"`.

Therefore, the compiler will accept if your code looks like this:

```js
interface ICarManufacturer { tyres: boolean; }

interface IAirplaneManufacturer { wings: boolean; }

interface IVehicle {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly price: number;
}

interface ICar extends IVehicle{
  readonly type: 'land';
  readonly manufacturers: ICarManufacturer[];
}

interface IAirplane extends IVehicle {
  readonly type: 'air';
  readonly manufacturers: IAirplaneManufacturer[];
}

type Vehicle = 
  | ICar
  | IAirplane


const vehicle = getVehicle(id); // Returns a "Vehicle"
if (vehicle.type === 'land') {
  processCarManufacturers(vehicle.manufacturers);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGE5QLJxAV3gTHymmQG9kwBPMgZwC5kAjAezYBsI8BuZAL4AoIaEixEKVAEFgUAA6c8EXASIkyUSsgDuoAOZNWHbn0Eix0IlIBqEABbAE3SkOTIycACZsQnGsjAXswEALYs0LxuHjw+fgHyUE4QIfjhkULCouBWkmiYWhAAHpAgXvRodo7OEBTRnnH+1DTyKcgA5Epl7VHuDb5NoXiEiBrQRhhYqiPEpNAA2gC6UVmWEkhosgpdKMWl5ZUOTi51fbEDAbStzO1wcj315-HIQ2qjc1ATW4rK0+ofSxWIiuKCqxxQAF5kNEAD75LCwzZyH4gCAiIReCDOLAoGD4EDEYC+ZCJNhIej0Ap-d6aegACleMzGn2Ykxww3+miWAEpmAA3NhBKKY7FkZB4glgIkgZD6CBgME1OlBVLpKC85CK7jCrFKMUIXz0MCBYLIMIRKBRIQGkBG5B8o41ZBQuUKx3cZVeblRYAwZB0h3VbgAOhBzohUM6eC87W5rncpPJlKmHJp4wD7ogwcZnPG3syQA)